# How to Fetch Data Form Many to Many relation table in Djnago?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I Have Many to Many Relationship tables.
One user can take Multiple Courses this is what i want to do.
My Models are

```
class CourseModel(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False)
    
    
class UserModel(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    usercourses=models.ManyToManyField(CourseModel) #this code is creating saperate table in my database
```

my new created table's data looks like below:

```
id : 1
usermodel_id : 7   # (any user_id can come here)
coursemodel_id : 10  #(any course id can come here)

id : 2
usermodel_id : 7
coursemodel_id : 11
```

As we can see in Above Data, user(7) taken multiple courses such as 10,11.
i Want to fetch all Courses of user(7)  form above data.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation many to many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```py
user = User.objects.get(pk=7)
user.usercourses.all() # gives all user (id=7) courses.
```